# Non-servlet Java HTTP server

Tags: java, http, webserver, httpserver

Weird question, but here it goes.

I've been looking for a Java HTTP server that is **NOT** servlet-compliant (don't ask me why). I could not find anything satisfactory like that so far (not on Google at least). I do **NOT** want Jetty, Tomcat, etc, I want something that is completely unrelated to the Servlet specification. Think of it as a Java equivalent of [Kayak](http://kayakhttp.com) (non-ASP.NET HTTP server for .NET).

Do you know any good HTTP server of this kind?

PS: Please guys avoid replying with "why not Jetty?", or "why reinvent the wheel?". If you have an actual answer to my question I will appreciate a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [Grizzly](http://grizzly.java.net/) is something for you.

Comment: Wow, I did not know Grizzly has an HTTP server implementation. I'm gonna try it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/) fairly often and have not had any problems with it. It's not really a web server container more than the ability to programatically host stuff.

Answer (score 0):

[Open source websers](http://java-source.net/open-source/web-servers), like tornado.

Answer (score 0):

Try [searching Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=tiny%20java%20http%20server) for "Tiny Java HTTP server"

One thing that comes to mind, is using [Webrick](https://web.archive.org/web/20121218013204/http://microjet.ath.cx:80/webrickguide/html/html_webrick.html) under JRuby (which is probably cheating, but so what?) :-)

Answer (score 0):

I've not heard of Kayak before, but the fact it says it is asynchronous, simple and easy to embed into applications would make me recommend:

http://simpleweb.sourceforge.net/

and possibly

http://vertx.io/

Answer (score 0):

It's right in your JDK: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/package-summary.html

Comment: The `HttpServer` class looks good, unfortunately it's bound to a specific JVM.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at [Restlet](http://www.restlet.org/). It provides an API aimed for RESTful applications, and it's not Servlet-compliant (although you can embedded in a Servlet environment if you need).

It can rely on a number of underlying libraries for its HTTP connectors. They should be a good starting point if you're looking for HTTP server libraries:

- [Simple](http://simpleweb.sourceforge.net/)
- [Jetty](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/)
- [Netty](https://netty.io/)
- [Grizzly](http://grizzly.java.net/)

Of course, some of these projects also support Servlets, but if you look at their core libraries, they also expose APIs that are not servlet-related.

Answer (score 0):

Creating an `HTTP` server yourself is by far non-trivial.
So if don't want to use for some reason any third party library then you have a lot of work to do.
There is an `HTTPServer` in `JDK` mentioned also by @ChristianSchlichtherle but it is under `com.sun.net.*` which means that you are not guaranteed whether it will continue to exist in a next release or you can find it in any JDK implementation. [Here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JDK-6/LightweightHTTPServer.htm) is an example code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The idea is to use a 3rd party library to run an instance of an HTTP server. The `HTTPServer` class is not a choice since it's bound to a specific JVM.

Comment: @Celio:I think that you are looking for a light HTTP implementation. That is what you mean non-servlet compliant.I think your best option would be to use jetty or tomcat (both have an embedded version so that you don't need a container).